# Strange output always occurs on MacOS but not on Ubuntu

Tags: c, macos, ubuntu

I'm able to make this C program work properly on Ubuntu, but on Mac it always gives me some weird output on the first line of the matrix.

When I try to print `temp[0][k]` it messes up the whole line! (You Need a file.txt to run the code)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void)
{
    int fd, sz;
    int size; //the nuber of bytes of the file
    int index = 0;
    int j, m, k, i = 0;
    int count, tot = 0;
    int plain_counter = 0;
    int encoded_counter = 0;

    struct stat st;
    stat("file_input.txt", &st);
    size = st.st_size;

    char c[size];
    fd = open("file_input.txt", O_RDONLY);
    if (fd < 0) { perror("r1"); exit(1); }

    sz = read(fd, c, size);
    printf("called read(%d, c, %i).  returned that" " %d bytes  were read.\n", fd, size, sz);
    c[sz] = '\0';
    printf("Those bytes are as follows: \n%s\n", c);

    for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
    {
        if (c[k] == '\n')
        {
            index++; //countin how many times the \n appear in the file
        }
    }

    char temp[index][1024]; //array to save modifived lines
    char plain[index][512]; //array to save plain lines
    char encoded[index][512]; //array to save encoded lines

    //Bring the string from C[] to temp[][] omitting < >
    for(j = 0 ; j < index; j++)
    {
        //printf("%i\n", j);
        while(c[i] != '\n')
        {
            //printf("j = %i , k = %i  ", j, k);
            if(c[i] != '<' && c[i] != '>')
            {
                temp[j][k] = c[i];
                //printf("%c", temp[j][k]); //if i print temp here it's perfect
                k++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        printf("temp[%i][%i] = %c\n", j, k, temp[j][k]);
        temp[j][k] = '\n';
        tot += k; 
        k = 0;
        i++;
    }

    temp[j][tot + 1] = '\0';

    //printf("0 0 = %c\n", temp[0][0]);

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = 0;

    //i print the temp array to check if it is well made
    while(j < index)
    {
        printf("j = %i, k = %i\n", j, k);
        while(temp[j][k] != '\n')
        {
            printf("%c", temp[j][k]); //the problem occurs here, in temp[0][k]!!
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");

        k = 0;
        j++;
    }
    printf("\n");

    //saving the plain text into te plain array and the encoded text into te encoded array
    //it works but the first line is a mess (ONLY ON MACOS)
    for ( j = 0 ; j < index; j++)
    {
        count = 0;
        i = 0;
        k = 0;
        m = 0;
        while(temp[j][i] != '\n'){  
            if(temp[j][i] != ';')
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    plain[j][k] = temp[j][i];
                    printf("%c", plain[j][k]);
                    k++;
                    plain_counter++;
                }else{
                    encoded[j][m] = temp[j][i];
                    printf("%c", encoded[j][m]);
                    m++;
                    encoded_counter++;

                }
            }
            else if(temp[j][i] == ';')
            {
                printf("\n");
                count = 1;          
            }
        i++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    plain[j][plain_counter + 1] = '\0';
    encoded[j][encoded_counter + 1] = '\0';
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are lacking or overwriting the null-terminator somewhere. Run a debugger and check your array boundaries.

Comment: Run your code through Vagrind.  If you're overstepping memory bounds, it should tell you.

Comment: in mac check for '\r'  for end line

Comment: @purec that was good advice 20+ years ago for "classic" MacOS but not since

Comment: If `sz` is `size` then `c[sz] = '\0'` is out of bounds. You probably want to allocate `size + 1` bytes.

Comment: One of the beauties of 'undefined behaviour' is that any result is OK, including "it appears to work as expected" and "it produces garbage in the output".  Both are perfectly acceptable responses to undefined behaviour.  Different systems are allowed to behave differently — all that tells you is that you were unlucky in the original environment in that you didn't get an early warning about the fact that your program is broken.  You also haven't shown an example input file — it isn't clear what came from the file and what was generated otherwise.  What is clear: you've not shown all the output.

Comment: @purec `'\n'` is C's portable newline abstraction. Even on a "classic" Mac you'd use `'\n'` for end-of-line (it just would have a numeric value of 13).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i edited the question to show everything

Comment: OK.  What code set is that file supposed to be in?  The legible tags appear to be Italian.  I'm not sure what the other tags are supposed to contain.  The message containing `libobjc.A.dylib` strongly suggests you have a pointer out of control — that doesn't appear in the data file, so you must be reading from some obscure arbitrary location in your executable.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the text il plain Italian and the encoded is the same text, I don't use pointer in the code because I wanted to avoid memory problems and I can't use easy C libraries because I'm forced to use system call. I still don't understand why the same code runs on Ubuntu with no problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that whilst you're taking into account that `read` doesn't add a `NUL` character to terminate the string and you're adding it yourself, you don't give the array enough space to store it. So you just need to increase the size when you create the array like this:

```
char c[size+1];
```

Just for completeness sake, you should also check the return value of `read` as it can be -1 if there is an error.

Spotted another couple of problems further on. You have this line:

```
temp[j][tot + 1] = '\0';
```

It comes after this for loop

```
for(j = 0 ; j < index; j++)
```

Once the loop has finished `j` will be out of bounds for `temp`. And really, that line should be inside the loop as you want to add the `\0` to every string in `temp`. So you should remove it and where you have this line:

```
    temp[j][k] = '\n';
```

Add this line to terminate the string.

```
    temp[j][k+1] = '\0';
```

And as for `k`, I can't see any sign that it set to 0 before this loop. You only reset it to 0 at the end so the first time around `k` could contain any value. Move the `k=0` to be the first thing that happens in the loop.

There could easily be other similar problems - this is where debugging your code using valgrind will a really good idea as it will tell you where these kinds of bugs are happening.

Comment: I've tried, it gave me the same error, I know that I need to check if read returns -1 but the code is still incomplete. And on Ubuntu VM this code works perfectly.

Comment: That'll be because Ubuntu clears it's memory where as other OSes initialise it to garbage to throw up these kinds of errors.

Comment: The line temp[ j ] [ tot + 1 ] is meant to be there because I don't want to end very string with \0 but just the last string so replace the last \n with \0, and even using c [ size + 1 ] the output is always the same.

Comment: @jacopo but what about my point about not setting `k` to 0 before you build `temp`? The last value it was set to is `size` from the previous loop.

Comment: And setting `temp[j][tot+1]` is wrong because `tot` is the sum of all values of `k`. If you only want to add the `NUL` to the last string, you want to track what the last value of `k` is and use that.

Comment: the main error was not putting k = 0, I still don't understand why it was working on Ubuntu but not on my Mac! thanks for the help and sorry for the stupid mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You never set your indices to 0!

My compiler emits a warning on line 37 :

```
warning: variable index is uninitialized when used here
    index++
```

Later after this loop:

```
for (k = 0; k < size; k++)
{
    if (c[k] == '\n')
    {
        index++;
    }
}
```

`k` has the value of `size`. But you use it nevertheless as if it was 0. It works for next line, because you reset it to 0 on end of loop.

Of course as shown by Chris, you should reserve some place for the terminating null in `sz` position:

```
char c[size + 1];
```

Last but not least, if your test file is not ended with a new line (not all editors add it on last line), your `index` value will be off by one...

May be others...

What you should have learned from that:

- always initialize automatic variables
- always ensure values of variables at the beginning of a loop
- use a debugger to control values at run time

My advices to go further:

- use `fgets` to read input by lines (much more robust than counting '\n' whatever the last line can be)
- write the general structure of the program in pseudo code before starting to code
- do add comments explaining what happens. If looks useless while you are writing the code, but greatly helps when you read it some weeks later

Comment: I would use way more efficient functions if I wasn't forced to use system call as I am. index is not set equals to 0 but I it perfectly works, the size of c is not a problem because the code fail the same even given more space to c.